# Is it possible to set class members through fetch() so they can be used in other class methods?

Tags: javascript, class, promise, fetch

I'm building a webapp that needs to display TIFF images in the browser (among other things) and am hitting a wall trying to properly organize the data.

I want to create a class that will hold the relevant data for the items I am working with so it can be used through class methods.  Because the data is retrieved through parsing a TIFF file from a server, this needs to be accomplished through something like the Fetch API.

In the example below I am fetching a TIFF from a local URL using Chrome Web Server, then creating and displaying it in a canvas using Tiff.js (https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master):

```
class boardImage {
    constructor(boardType) {
        this.boardType = boardType;
        this.boardURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8887/28431413.Display.' + this.boardType + '.tif'
        this.canvas;
        this.width;
        this.height;
        this.loadImage()
    }

    async loadImage() {
        fetch(this.boardURL)
            .then((response) => {
                response.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
                    let tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
                    this.width = tiff.width();
                    this.height = tiff.height();
                    this.canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
                    if (this.canvas) {
                        this.canvas.classList.add("boardimage");
                        this.canvas.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + this.width + 'px; height: ' + this.height + 'px;');

                        // this works but I don't want to call this here
                        this.displayImage();
                    }
                })
            })
    }

    displayImage() {
        document.getElementById("boardview").append(this.canvas);
    }

}
```

The above code works because `displayImage()` is called within the chain.  When I call it outside of the chain the canvas images are undefined.  **In either situation** the class members are set properly and I can see the appropriate values for canvas, width, and height in the browser console.  I would like to just load the relevant data when I instantiate the class, and the call methods like `displayImage()` or reference member variables when they need to be.

I understand that this is asynchronous behavior, but I don't know how to handle it properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) for a proper solution

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, that link has some good explanations that outline some better looking approaches to this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with async and await:

```
class boardImage {
constructor(boardType) {
    this.boardType = boardType;
    this.boardURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8887/28431413.Display.' + this.boardType + '.tif'
    this.canvas;
    this.width;
    this.height;
}

async loadImage() {
    let response = await fetch(this.boardURL)
    let buffer  = await response.arrayBuffer()
    let tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});
    this.width = tiff.width();
    this.height = tiff.height();
    this.canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
    if (this.canvas) {
        this.canvas.classList.add("boardimage");
        this.canvas.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + this.width + 'px; height: ' + this.height + 'px;');
    }
}

displayImage() {
    document.getElementById("boardview").append(this.canvas);
}

}

let image = new boardImage("example")
image.loadImage().then((response) => {
    image.displayImage()
})
```

You create a `boardImage` then call the loadImage method which returns a promise. After the promise resolves you display the canvas.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: you could do that ... if loadImage returned a promise, which it doesn't

Comment: @JaromandaX loadImage is async which means it returns a promise even if it is not specified.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say that it returns a pointless promise unrelated to the asynchronous task within it

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited my post to show a better way of doing it.

Comment: No, that's not a good way of doing it. Don't go back to callbacks without error handling when you already have promises.

Comment: @Bergi I am sorry, I think I might have given a better answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still not optimal (the class methods can't be used arbitrarily, `displayImage` doesn't need an instance but takes all data via arguments), but much better.

Comment: @Bergi Are you saying I should remove the argument and make it use `this.canvas`? I thought making `displayImage` take an argument would prevent it from being called before loading.

Comment: This answer works and gets the job done.  I appreciate the feedback from @Bergi, and the link posted in the question above that provides insight to some better ways of handling this